# debugging using gdb - properly using the -g flag with several files

Tags: makefile, gdb

I'm trying to debug using gdb running it through emacs, with no success. I keep on getting the well known "no debugging symbol found". I assume the problem is in the way I compile using the -g flag, but I can't tell where is my mistake. Here is the makefile:

```
all: tree

tree: main.o OctTree.o my_vec.o runge_kutta.o initialize.o global.o
    g++ -g -o tree main.o OctTree.o my_vec.o runge_kutta.o initialize.o global.o -lm

main.o: main.cpp OctTree.h my_vec.h global.h
    g++ -g -o3 main.cpp -o main.o 

my_vec.o: my_vec.cpp my_vec.h
    g++ -g -o3 my_vec.cpp -o my_vec.o

OctTree.o: OctTree.cpp OctTree.h my_vec.h global.h
    g++ -g -o3 OctTree.cpp -o OctTree.o

runge_kutta.o: runge_kutta.cpp OctTree.h my_vec.h global.h
    g++ -g -o3 runge_kutta.cpp -o runge_kutta.o

initialize.o: initialize.cpp my_vec.h OctTree.h global.h
    g++ -g -o3 initialize.cpp -o initialize.o

global.o : global.cpp global.h
    g++ -g -o3 global.cpp -o global.o

clean: 
    rm main.o my_vec.o OctTree.o runge_kutta.o initialize.o global.o-f
```

when I try running gdb I get this message:
Reading symbols from /home/alexander/physics with computer/final/tree...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

thank you very much!

Comment: it would help if you used a slightly more dynamic makefile.  Also, disable optimization.

Comment: I tried disabling the optimization, but it didn't help.

Comment: what do you mean by a 'more dynamic makefile'?

Comment: I posted an answer with an example.  How are you running the debugger?

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work. I'm lunching the gdb through emacs, and that's the first comment I get. I'm new to emacs and to the gdb, so I'm not sure I know what you mean by "a make clean". Do you mean I should add "$(MAKE) clean" in the "clean" section at the end of the file? If so, it doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't understand how this makefile can work. You're trying to build object files (e.g. `OctTree.o`) without the `-c` option, which means that the build should fail for any source file that doesn't have a `main()` function (which should be most of them), and the linker should refuse to link executables to build `tree`.

Comment: @Beta: gcc is pretty smart.  It probably knows what to do with a .cpp file if you specify that whatever it does should produce a .o file.  OP: open a console, navigate to the directory your code is in, and run `make clean`.  Then `make`, and then try GDB again.

Comment: @Wug, try it. Although gcc and g++ are smart enough to build object files without being told how, they are also well enough designed that if you **tell them** to build something else and call it "foo.o", that's what they'll do. And a good thing too, or they'd be a pain to work with.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not somewhere I can try it (otherwise I would have).  Maybe OP is using an old, outdated, or quirky version.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off taking advantage of make's features to make your makefile easier to change.  For example:

```
# all cpp files (add files here if you add more to your project)
SRC_FILES = main.cpp my_vec.cpp OctTree.cpp runge_kutta.cpp initialize.cpp global.cpp
OBJ_FILES = $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC_FILES))) # autogenerated

# flags, options, and other crap
OUTPUT = tree
CXX_FLAGS = -c -g # -O3 # disable optimization for now
CXX_FLAGS_LINK = -g
LIBS = -lm

# first target
all: tree

# tree target: requires all object files, links them into output executable
tree: $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ $(CXX_FLAGS_LINK) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBS)

# generic target for any cpp file
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(CXX_FLAGS) -o %.o %.cpp

# clean target
clean: 
    rm main.o my_vec.o OctTree.o runge_kutta.o initialize.o global.o -f

# specific dependencies for each file
# you can generate these with g++ -MM <filename.cpp>
main.o: main.cpp OctTree.h my_vec.h global.h
my_vec.o: my_vec.cpp my_vec.h
OctTree.o: OctTree.cpp OctTree.h my_vec.h global.h
runge_kutta.o: runge_kutta.cpp OctTree.h my_vec.h global.h
initialize.o: initialize.cpp my_vec.h OctTree.h global.h
global.o : global.cpp global.h
```

I suspect the issue you're having relates to the lengths the compiler is going to to efficientize your code at O3.  Try again with no optimization and see if that works for you.

I have not tested this makefile at all.

## Edit:

OK, you've tried disabling optimization.  you've tried a `make clean` and recompile with optimization off?  How are you launching the debugger?  Leave optimization off, it doesn't get along well with debugging, even if GDB has a different gripe right now.  Did you forget to rebuild your sources?

Answer (score 1):

> when I try running gdb I get this message: Reading symbols from /home/alexander/physics with computer/final/tree...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

It seems pretty clear that your build actually does contain debug info. Therefore it *must* be that you are debugging something *other* than what you've built (some other copy of `tree`).

You should

1. Confirm that the binary has debug info. For example:

   ```
    cd /home/alexander/physics/computer/final
    readelf -wl tree | grep 'runge_kutta\.cpp'
   ```

   should produce some output. And

   ```
    readelf -w tree
   ```

   should produce *a lot* of output.
2. Confirm that you can debug this binary outside of emacs:

   ```
   gdb ./tree
   ```

   This should *not* produce `no debugging symbols found`
3. Now debug this binary in emacs:

   ```
   M-x gdb
   ```

   complete the command to be `gdb /home/alexander/physics/computer/final/tree`

   If step 2 worked, then step 3 will not produce `no debugging symbols found` either.